# What does the "force" parameter do in UIView.endEditing?

Tags: ios, swift

In what situation will `self.view.endEditing(true)` and `self.view.endEditing(false)` produce different results?

---

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting) for `func endEditing(force: Bool) -> Bool` state the following for  the parameter `force`:

> Specify `true` to force the first responder to resign, regardless of whether it wants to do so.

Comment: I'd guess this, you should test it out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canResignFirstResponder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, if `canResignFirstResponder` returns false, `self.view.endEditing(true)` will cause the control to lose focus but `self.view.endEditing(false)` will not.